# Bad Superblock screwed 16.04 install

Tags: 16.04, busybox

A few days ago, with the release of 16.04 LTS, I opted to upgrade. I ran the install tool on the desktop, and I thought it would be a simple process to upgrade from 14.04.

There were a few hiccups throughout the process, which are beyond my technical skills to accurately convey. The result of these is quite annoying however, my laptop will no longer boot.

That is to say, when I do boot, I'm pulled through to a BusyBox terminal, with no other option.

I've googled the problem already, I have an issue with a bad superblock, and have attempted to follow the steps with a live USB as presented in [this useful guide](/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox).

I get to the last stage, and I'm presented with the text:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount: mount /dev/sda1 on /mnt failed: Structure needs cleaning
```

How do I get past this point? I've tried a fresh install where I've wiped the hard drive completely, which I thought might have removed any issues with the hard drive. I have no files on the computer which need to be saved, but I use the machine regularly and would like to restore it to full working order (something I never had an issue with when using 14.04)

As hinted, I'm not much of a tech guy, so please aim answers at an idiot's level. Thank you!

Comment: I've since tried installing Linux Mint, which booted up but didn't really work properly, Ubuntu has the problem every time I attempt to reinstall 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you fixed this problem. I just upgraded fro Ubuntu 14.10 to Ubuntu 16.04.1. when rebooting I went into busybox. I used an old live cd of Ubuntu 13.10 but any live cd prob work and I typed in disks, in the launcher and opened the program disks and made sure the hard drive was not mounted, then opened a terminal and on my case the busybox msg said sda1 needed manual check or something so i did fsdk /dev/sda1 in the terminal with the drive not mounted (booted into live CD). Then rebooted and went into the recovery menu and selected fsck on the menu again to make sure then it booted OK.